# Command : \noindent not working

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I'm want a simple paragraph in my document with no indentation. I'm using the command `\noindent` at the beginning of the paragraph, But its not working. Here's the code I'm using

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Para \\}
\noindent
Blah blah blah ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anybody tell me why its not working. I'm using 'Texworks'

Comment: make sure you didnot redefine `\paragraph`

Comment: `\noindent` _is_ working (but does nothing there as para is not indented already). So you need to say what you wanted to happen. Is the image intended to show your required output?

Comment: I've edited the code please see again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you show is not generated by posted code, in `article` class `\paragraph` is an inline heading so produces

**Para** Blah blah

The word **Para** is not indented so it is hard to guess what effect you intended `\noindent` to have. Note that `\paragraph` is a *section head* and should only be used in the sequence `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`. `\noindent` should rarely (arguably never) be used within the document and certainly never applied to a heading.

If you want to redefine `\paragraph` to be a display heading rather than inline, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                    {1sp}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\paragraph{Para}
Blah blah blah ...
\end{document}
```

but as noted above `\paragraph` should only follow `\subsubsection`

Comment: I've edited the code please see again

Comment: @Atinesh updated answer